# Pre Calculus Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The questions is:

$$\dfrac{3(x+2)^2(x-3)^2 - 2(x+2)^3(x-3)}{(x-3)^4}$$

My answer is: $$\dfrac{3(x+2)^2 + 6x^2-4}{(x-3)^2}$$

Am I right? If not, where have I failed?

Comment: First, it's hard to tell what you're asking: where's that denominator? At least use parentheses (much better and clearer if you use LaTeX, of course). Second, what's the question?! There's only one expression...do you have to simplify it or what?

Comment: Is there a reason for not factoring the 2 out of the last 2 terms in the numerator? As it stands, this looks a bit odd as I'd either expand and factor the numerator or complete the factoring of those last terms myself.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \begin{align}\dfrac{3(x+2)^2(x-3)^2 - 2(x+2)^3(x-3)}{(x-3)^4}&=
\dfrac{(x-3)(3(x-3)(x+2)^2-2(x+2)^3)}
{(x-3)^4}\\
&=           \dfrac{3(x-3)(x+2)^2-2(x+2)^3}{(x-3)^3}\\
&= \dfrac{(x+2)^2(2(x-3)-2(x+2))}{(x-3)^3} \\
&= \dfrac{(x+2)^2(3x-9-2x-4)}{(x-3)^3}\\
&= \dfrac{(x+2)^2(x-13)}{(x-3)^3}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Trusty [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) tells me:

```
factor(ratsimp((3*(x + 2)^2 * (x - 3)^2 - 2 * (x + 2)^3 * (x - 3))/(x - 3)^4));
```

is:
$$
\frac{(x - 13) (x + 2)^2}{(x - 3)^3}
$$

A trick that helps catch silly errors while simplifying is to replace some simple values, like $x = 0$ and $x = \pm 1$ in the expresssions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{3(x+2)^2(x-3)^2 - 2(x+2)^3(x-3)}{(x-3)^4}$$
Let's factor the $(x-3)$ in the numerator and denominator.
$$\dfrac{(x-3)\left[3(x+2)^2(x-3) - 2(x+2)^3\right]}{(x-3)(x-3)^3}$$
Now we can cancel out $(x-3)$ in the numerator and the denominator. That gives us:
$$\dfrac{3(x+2)^2(x-3) - 2(x+2)^3}{(x-3)^3}$$
Let us expand the equation.
$$\dfrac{3(x+2)^2(x-3) - 2(x+2)^3}{(x-3)^3}$$
$$=\dfrac{3(x^2+4x+4)(x-3)+2(x^3-6x^2+12x-8)}{x^3-9x^2+27x-27}$$
$$=\dfrac{3x^3-3x^2+4x^2-12x+4x-12+2x^3-12x^2+24x+16}{x^3-9x^2+27x-27}$$
Combine like terms:
$$\dfrac{3x^3-3x^2+4x^2-12x+4x-12+2x^3-12x^2+24x+16}{x^3-9x^2+27x-27}$$
$$=\dfrac{5x^3-11x^2-14x+4}{x^3-9x^2+27x-27}$$
We cannot factor the numerator nor simplify it any further. So, the answer to your question is:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\dfrac{3(x+2)^2(x-3)^2 - 2(x+2)^3(x-3)}{(x-3)^4}=\dfrac{5x^3-11x^2-14x+4}{x^3-9x^2+27x-27}}$$